# can static analysis analyse a github repository and find out what are the technologies (language/libraries ..etc.) used?

Tags: github, static, libraries, analysis

Is static analysis or build manager tools able to analyse a github repository and find out what are the technologies (languages/libraries .. etc.) used, for example say this github repo. is using java, spring and detect versions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library used on GitHub.com to detect blob languages, ignore binary or vendor files, suppress generated files in diffs, and generate language breakdown graphs.

https://github.com/github/linguist

Using that library, you can get some data about a repository.